# How to fix shifting text in select box while zooming in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, zooming

when selecting item in drop down list then zooming in IE selected text hiding below select input area or shifting down. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Could we see some of your HTML and CSS that is relevant to the question please? Might just be a problem with font-size being declared in px instead of em, or it could be something else entirely. No way to know without some code to look at.

Comment: just open some select input with option data and zoom-in and zoom-out in IE for example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option